Как в pymongo обновить последний элемент массива?
Использую motor + pymongo
Коллекция имеет следующий вид записей:
{
    '_id':0,
    'data':[0,1,2],
    'profit':30
},
{
    '_id':1,
    'data':[0,12,25],
    'profit':37
}

Хочу обновить у записи поле data увеличив последний элемент массива на значение поля profit соответствующей записи.
Т. е. при обновлении элемента с id = 1
Получится следующее:
{
    '_id':1,
    'data':[0,12,62],
    'profit':37
}

Как можно это сделать ?
Псевдокод выглядит как-то так:
await collection.update_one(
    {"_id":1},
    {'$inc':{
        'data.-1':"$profit"
    }}
)

